# ReSharper post clean-up object initializers violate StyleCop rules

Tags: resharper

After updating Resharper and StyleCop, post clean-up object initializers now look like this:

```
var foo = new Foo {
  Bar = 1,
  Baz = 2
}
```

How I want them to look, and how StyleCop expects them to look is:

```
var foo = new Foo 
{
  Bar = 1,
  Baz = 2
}
```

I've been playing with the line brake and brace settings, but am not having any luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I had line wrapping turned off, but had the chop always setting enabled for object initializers. Evidently, the chop always setting for line wrapping ignores the braces setting for object initializers.

Comment: Chop always doesn't work correctly without line wrapping - this is a known bug. But you can set large enough right margin (MaxInt) to get around it.

Answer (score 0):

Double check some of your settings and maybe post what you have them set to. Under:

> ReSharper Settings > Code Editing > C# > Formatting Style > Braces Layout

You should check that

> Array and object initializer

is set to

> At next line (BSD style)

Also check your Visual Studio Settings so that

> Text Editor > C# > Formatting > New Lines > New Line options for braces > Place open brace on new line for object initializers

is checked